# Compiling Boost.python and cuda code

Tags: boost, cuda, boost-python, bjam, nvcc

I would like to compile `parallel.cu` and `python_wrapper.cpp` where `python_wrapper.cpp` use `Boost.python` to expose the method in `parallel.cu` to python.
I'm new to both `cuda` and `Boost.python`.
From their manual and google, I couldn't find how to make them talk.
Some site says, that I should do something like

```
nvcc -o parallel.cu
g++ -o python_wrapper.cpp
g++ parallel.o python_wrapper.o
```

But the only way I know to compile a `Boost.python` code is to use `bjam`.
There have been attempt to integrate `nvcc` into `bjam`, but I couldn't make them work.

parallel.cuh

```
__global__ void parallel_work();
int do_parallel_work();
```

python_wrapper.cpp

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include "parallel.cuh"

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(parallel_ext){
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("parallel", do_parallel_work);
}
```

How can I compile these files?
I have heard of `PyCuda`, but I need to include `Boost` and `thrust` library in my `.cu` files.
Also, if possible, I would like to stick to a standard command line driven compilation process.

Comment: It's quite possible to compile Boost.Python code without bjam (and I think it's even easier than trying to use bjam).  You basically just need to compile a shared library that links to both the Python and Boost.Python shared libraries, and use include paths to both the Python and Boost.Python headers.

Comment: I recommend using the libraries that already exist for integrating CUDA with Python.  Take a closer look at PyCUDA.  Also, take a look at ArrayFire (which is the one I work on).  Google "gpu python".  Would those help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a static or dynamic library with the CUDA functions and link it in. That is, use nvcc to create the library and then, in a separate step, use g++ to create the Python module and link in the library.

Comment: Yeah, the nvcc preprocessors can't handle *really* complex C++ template constructs correctly, and boost is the most notorious example of code which can't compile with nvcc steerage.

Answer (score 1):

To integrate code compiled with nvcc and code compiled with g++, I just defined a new compile rule for cuda sources, stored in .cu files to .o

Rules to compile `.cu` to `.o` are stored in a `nvcc.jam` file which I import from my Jamroot.

Below is my nvcc.jam file

```
import type ;
type.register CUDA : cu ;

import generators ;
generators.register-standard nvcc.compile : CUDA : OBJ ;

actions compile
{
    "/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\"  -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\"  -m64 --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing  -I. -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/home/user/GPU/SDK/C/common/inc -I/home/user/GPU/SDK/shared/inc -DUNIX -O2   -o $(<) -c $(>)
}
```

Obviously it's a bit of a hack as cuda installation path are hardcoded, but it works fine for my need. I would love having equivalent (hopefully cleaner) bjam extension distributed from NVidia SDK.

In the main project file I can then define compilation rules using both .cpp and .cu files like:

```
exe testdraw
:
    gpu/drawable.cu
    gpu/testdraw.cpp
    gpu/cudacommon.cu
    gpu/host.cpp
    gpu/opencl.cpp
    gpu/opencl24.cpp

    png
    z
    cl
    libboost_program_options

    cuda
    cudart
    cublas
:
;
```

`cuda`, `cudart` and `cublas` being the usual cuda libs declared as usual.

```
lib cudart : : <name>cudart ;
lib cuda : : <name>cuda ;
lib cublas : : <name>cublas ;
```